# Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM WebAPI Deprecation replacement

Tags: javascript, c#, rest, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I work with Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM Online with several customers. I used to work with the **Xrm.WebApi** object model in order to retrieve entities.

Recently I was searching how to create entities with this object and realized that it won't be longer accesible since they will deprecate this soon and [CDS](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/perform-operations-web-api) is the replacement.

So, according to [CRM documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/mt593051(v=crm.8)) (provided in the same CRM), the URL `https://organiation.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/` won't be accessible? How to work with AJAX requests to perform CRUD operations then?

Any comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the web api will allow you to access CDS as well as D365, and I have never heard about it being deprecated. Did you see an article to that effect?

You can go into Settings > Customizations > Developer Resources and inspect the Instance Web API. In my v9.1 trial org it's still showing: `https://myOrg.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/`

What is deprecated is the v2011 SOAP endpoint, which appears as the Organization Service under the Developer Resources:
`https://myOrg.api.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc`

Comment: Look at this documentation seen over the provided API URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/mt593051(v=crm.8) 
It refers to the CDS API

Comment: Thanks. Where does it say that the Dynamics 365 Web API is being deprecated?

Comment: Here it says: https://i.imgur.com/Rw7hxLm.png and when clicking on "Recommended version" it redirects me to that CDS documentation.

Comment: That notice refers to the documentation rather than the WebAPI itself. As far as I know, the CDS WebAPI _is_ the Dynamics 365 WebAPI.

Comment: Okay then. I get it. Thank you.